# How to set the views in linear layout so that it fits in from start to end screen with a certain number of elements that are in a one row?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I have 14 (views) horizontal lines in LinearLayout and it should fit in any screen, so is there any idea how to set width between lines to fit from start to end at any screen size?
See the image how it looks:
[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx4Yx.png)

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <View
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blueTextColor" />
        
        <View
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
            android:background="@color/blueTextColor"/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/fourteen"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
            android:background="@color/blueTextColor" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

I try this but it not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but I think @GuseeMofiddin answer doesn't work as You want because it expands the view to the full width and You want it to be just `1dp`. You can Use constraint layout and chains to do it. Example:

1. Create Your layout like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000AA" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000AA" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000AA" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000AA" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2. Now You have to create horizontal chains.

First, select them all (click on `one`, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then click on `four`)

[image]

Next right-click and select this:

[image]

Your XML file should look like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000AA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000AA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/three"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000AA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/four"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/two" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000AA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/three" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result on two different devices:

[image]

(this method doesn't create a view on the left and right edge. To do it just add one of the left and right edge and then create chain but don't include them)

---

Edit to answer comment: To add the bottom and top margin to specific view You have to set `height` to `0dp` and set top and bottom constraint to top and bottom of the parent. The view should look like this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#0000AA"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/three"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to set

```
android:weightSum="14"
```

to your parent LinearLayout and

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to your child views, Please try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="14">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```